# Check if an account# exist in another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider the following

```
-- Get all objects from database A
use database_a;    

select o.objectnumber
into #temp
from EDDSDBO.objects o
group by d.objectnumber;

-- #temp holds 0001, 0002

-- Get all objects from database B
use database_b;

select o.objectnumber,
case when o.objectnumer in #temp then 1 else 0 end as Match
from EDDSDBO.objects o
group by o.objectnumber;

-- Expected output

objectnumber Match
0001         1
0002         1
0003         0
```

But I get an error: `incorrect syntax near objectnumber`.

I cannot seem to get this query right. What is the right syntax here?

Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

P.S. I'm on SQL Server 2008

Comment: Shouldn't that be `group by o.objectnumber;` and `case when o.objectnumber in`?

Comment: You can't do `WHEN x IN table`. You need something like `WHEN x IN (SELECT y FROM table)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If objectnumber is unique in each table, then you can just use `LEFT JOIN` with a 3 part object name:

```
SELECT  b.objectnumber,
        Match = CASE WHEN a.objectnumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM    database_b.EDDSDBO.objects b
        LEFT JOIN database_a.EDDSDBO.objects a
            ON a.objectnumber = b.objectnumber
```

If it is not unique, you can still do this, but you will need to use group by and an aggregate:

```
SELECT  b.objectnumber,
        Match = MAX(CASE WHEN a.objectnumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM    database_b.EDDSDBO.objects b
        LEFT JOIN database_a.EDDSDBO.objects a
            ON a.objectnumber = b.objectnumber
GROUP BY b.objectnumber;
```

The important part is there is no need to use a temporary table, this is unnecessary overhead on tempdb, and you also lose the use of any index on `objectnumber`.

Comment: Thanks, works great. But how would I be able to use a `WHERE Match = 1` clause?

Comment: If you only want matches just change the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

Change the second part of your query to

```
use database_b;

select o.objectnumber,
case when o.objectnumer in (select distinct objectnumber from #temp) then 1 
else 0 end as Match
from EDDSDBO.objects o
group by o.objectnumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use the GROUP BY clause for this example.

The match column is used to show whether a row exists in tableB for some value of objectnumber in tableA. If you only want to indicate the existence of a row in tableB, and not show the number of rows,  then you do not need to use the GROUP BY clause.

The first step should be to create a new set that contains only the set of rows from tableA that you want to compare against tableB. You can then create a sub-query to indicate whether tableA.objectnumber exists in tableB, using the NOT EXISTS operator.

```
With SubsetA(objectnumber) as (
select distinct objectnumber
from tableA)

select sa.objectnumber, 
(case when exists (select null from tableB tb where sa.objectnumber = tb.objectnumber) then 1 else 0 end) as Match
from SubsetA sa
```

Comment: You don't actually gain anything by removing the `GROUP BY` and replacing it with `DISTINCT`, it will still use exactly the same IO reads and sort operation to remove duplicates.

Comment: Using GROUP BY and the DISTINCT keywords in this example may yield the same execution plan. However, using GROUP BY is semantically incorrect; the purpose of the query is to indicate a match between a subset of rows in tableA, and tableB. The DISTINCT keyword is used to express the intent in creating the subset. A GROUP BY is not an appropriate construct to use in this type of problem.